# What would it mean if told to have tendencies to misinterpret punctuation for subordination

Tags: punctuation

[image]
Part of School report

What would it mean if told to have tendencies to misinterpret punctuation for subordination

Comment: Probably misuse / insufficient knowledge of _subordinate clauses_ (see [here](https://www.theschoolrun.com/what-is-a-clause) or [here](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/what-is-a-subordinate-clause) for example).

Comment: As Summer's parent, I would ask nicely for a written example of this pattern of mistakes that she makes. The formality of the report makes her sound like she doesn't read the social cues of the written word.

Comment: Summer uses commas correctly when citing a quotation (inverted commas) but otherwise forgets how to properly use commas.  Thus, she needs to focus on mastering use of commas in complex sentences, especially when using subordinate clauses.  Whoever wrote this drivel needs  to learn how to write more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

I'd assume that they're talking about **[subordinate clauses](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subordinateclause.htm)**, eg

"After I got back from work, I went straight to the fridge and grabbed a beer".

Here, "After I got back from work" can be called *the subordinate clause.*

They use "subordinate conjunctions", which are words like "after", "before", "because" etc.

[Subordination](https://www.thoughtco.com/subordination-grammar-1692155) is a name for the process of taking two seperate sentences and making them into one:  one sentence becomes the subordinate clause, and so the process can be called "subordination".

Eg, two sentences:

*"I got back from work.  I then went straight to the fridge and grabbed a beer."* -> subordination process -> *"After I got back from work, I went straight to the fridge and grabbed a beer."*

I'm not sure what the teacher means about punctuation, but my guess would be that it's to do with the use of a comma between the main clause and subordinate clause.  Maybe you have seen a comma used in other contexts and mistakenly marked the sentence as having a subordinate clause?  Without any examples it's hard to say.